# Automate Extended Validation (EV) code signing After Windows 10

Tags: passwords, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, authenticode

On this brilliant thread:

[Automate Extended Validation (EV) code signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927895/automate-extended-validation-ev-code-signing)

There are instructions about how to setup SafeNet Authentication client to avoid typing the password each time singtool is used. The proposed solution is:

1) Use "Enable single logon" on "Client Settings"
2) Use a c# app to inject the password to the GUI

We found that option 1 was enough for us and it has been working for 9 months. Now it is not working anymore and signtool has started to ask for the password each time it is used.

Two things changed since the last week:
1) we updated windows 10 to the latest build (1607)
2) we changed the source code root directory so the input parameters to signtool are not the same

I don't know how SafeNet handles the "single logon" so I don't know what's happening and how to fix it. Some people suggest to uninstall Safenet and install it again (that might work) the alternative is to go option 2 and create a wrapper application to sign and inject the password to the GUI.

The question is Do you know it there is an alternative method? do you know how "single logon" works so I can have more control over the process?

Regards

Comment: I'm running SafeNet client on Windows 10 latest version and it works fine. However, I had a lot of garbage user certificates in the SafeNet client that I had to remove. In the client, check in settings (the gear icon): Tokens/eToken Pro Java/User Certificates, you should see only certificates that you know.

Answer (score 0):

SafeNet upgraded their client and the single logon started working again. Thanks to the SafeNet team