# SignTool under Jenkins cannot find matching certificate with USB Token

Tags: jenkins, clickonce, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, signtool

I want to build and code-sign a WPF application and deploy it using ClickOnce using Jenkins.

My setup is:

- Jenkins (newest version, running Admin)
- certificate on a USB token, [activated single logon in SafeNet Client](https://xrstf.de/2018/03/safenet-token-code-signing-gitlab-ci/) since the USB token shows a pop-up to enter the token password
- running `signtool.exe sign /a /v "<path>\Shared.dll"` in the admin console works well
- running the same command as an AfterCompile/AfterPublish build command results in the following error: `SignTool error : No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.`

Found a few related issues [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!searchin/jenkinsci-users/signtool%7Csort:date/jenkinsci-users/RQyUWZilrRE/DeoJ94ujCQAJ) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927895/automate-extended-validation-ev-code-signing), but no solutions yet.

How can I make sure the Jenkins service finds the USB token when running the signtool command?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running jenkins as a windows service you need to change properties of Jenkins from services. [image: Jenkins Service]

Right-click and select properties. On the "Log On" tab, select "this account" and enter your credentials.

[image: Log On Screen]

Do not forget to check "enable single sign on" from the SafeNet Authentication Client as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26126701/517134)

To sign with USB token;

```
"signtool.exe" sign /a /tr http://timestamp.globalsign.com/?signature=sha2 /td SHA256 "your_file"
```

It worked for me. I hope it helps you, too.