# Unable to make Azure Agent Service run as my self

Tags: windows, service, windows-10, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I'm trying to work around a problem with my Self-hosted Azure Pipeline agent.  One of the workarounds listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60763831) is to make the agent log on as myself, (instead of as the current, "Network Service" account it uses).

So I tried that.  I went to the Services app, edited the "Azure Pipelines Agent" service and changed the user to be myself.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Windows then tells me that I'll need to stop the service and restart it.  But when I do that, I get an error dialog with Error 1069: "The service did not start due to a logon failure"

I have tried to use both my Windows 10 Logon PIN (that I type to login when I sit down at the machine) as the password as well as my Azure AD password for our organization that lets me log on to all our resources.  Neither one works.

I know I have the correct account.  I don't have any other organization passwords that I know of.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Change the logon user on DevOps agent services won't work.

If you'd like to run the agent with specific account, you need to uninstall the agent(`config.cmd remove`), then reconfigure the DevOps agent, type your account as below during the configuration.

[image]

You can validate the user account in DevOps pipeline with below task:

```
pool: self2
- script: whoami
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need..  I will try this tomorrow when I am back in the office and report back.  Thank you!

Comment: Well noted! Thanks for the info! Happy coding!

Comment: Hi @Joe, how is it going? If it works, could you please kindly help to mark it? Let me know if there's any queires.

Comment: I didn't manage to get back to the office until today.  I promise I will post back here as soon as I know something