# Automate Extended Validation (EV) code signing with Yubico Yubikey

Tags: code-signing, signtool, yubikey

I want to EV Code sign using a private key on a Yubico Yubikey 5 using `signtool.exe`, However everytime I sign a file, it prompts for the password. I would like the entry of this key to be automated as part of a build pipeline triggered on a secure machine.

I previously used a Safenet token and was able to do this using solutions from
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927895/automate-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-with-safenet-etoken), however my understanding is that this functionality was a specific implementation for the `eToken Cryptographic Security Provider` used by `Safenet`.

I have exported the public certificate from the Yubikey and used `certutil` to dump info about the key container (which is a `GUID` like `0bababab-0000-aaaa-baba-cdcdcdcdcdcd`) and the `CSP` which is `Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider` but when I use this info I get the following issue:

```
signtool sign /f <cert file>.crt /csp "Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider" /v /kc <container_id>
Error information: "CryptExportPublicKeyInfoEx failed" (-2146893819/0x80090005)
SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `Microsoft Smart Card` support the Yubikey also supports `PKCS11`. This interface isn't natively supported by `signtool.exe` but it is supported by third party tools like `osslsigncode` **which allows the key password to be supplied over the CLI**.

Here's how I got it working:

1. Download and install `OpenSSL` i.e. from [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)
   **Important:** make sure to install it to `C:\OpenSSL-Win64` instead of the default of `C\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64`
2. Download and install the `yubico-piv-tool` i.e. from [here](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-piv-tool/) and note the location of the file `libykcs11.dll` which should be at `C:\Program Files\Yubico\Yubico PIV Tool\bin`
   **Important:** Add this path to your `PATH` variable or `osslsigncode` won't work.
3. Clone or download the source for [`libp11`](https://github.com/OpenSC/libp11/releases)
4. Compile `libp11` using `nmake`, more detailed instructions [here](https://docs.digicert.com/en/digicert-keylocker/sign-with-digicert-signing-tools/third-party-signing-tool-integrations/configure-openssl-for-signing-with-pkcs11.html). **Note:** The current version of the make file is sensitive to `OpenSSL` being installed to the directory in **Step 1**
5. Note the location of `pkcs11.dll` which is produced from **Step 4** this will be our `pkcs11engine` for `osslsigncode`
6. Download `osslsigncode` i.e. from [here](https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode/releases) and add its location to your `PATH` variable
7. Use [Yubikey Manager](https://www.yubico.com/support/download/yubikey-manager/) to export the public certificate to a `.crt` file and note its location
8. Finally you can use the following command:
   `osslsigncode sign -pkcs11module <location_of_libykcs11.dll> -pkcs11engine <location_of_pkcs11.dll> -pass <yubikey_passcode> -ts <timestamp_server_url> -key "pkcs11:id=%01" -certs <path_to_public_cert.crt> -in "input_file.exe" -out "output_file.exe"`

Additional resources:

- [Additional info on Yubikeys support for PKCS11](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-piv-tool/YKCS11/)
- [OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC) particularly the `pkcs11-tool` was extremely useful in getting this running

Answer (score 1):

Here is my `s.bat` based on [`osslsigncode.exe`](https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode/releases/download/2.7/osslsigncode-2.7-windows-x64-vs.zip), [`libykcs11.dll`](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-piv-tool/Releases/yubico-piv-tool-2.5.1-win64.msi) and [`pkcs11.dll`](https://dl.unicontsoft.com/upload/pkcs11.zip) (x64 release)

Usage: `s.bat myproject.exe`

```dos
@echo off
setlocal

if "%1"=="" echo usage: %~nx0 ^<myproject.exe^> & goto :eof

call :codesign "%~1" ^
    "D:\TEMP\osslsigncode-2.7-windows-x64-vs\bin\osslsigncode.exe" ^
    "C:\Program Files\Yubico\Yubico PIV Tool\bin\libykcs11.dll" ^
    "C:\Work\Temp\libp11\src\pkcs11.dll" ^
    "C:\Work\Certificates\SSL.com\unicont soft ltd.chained_1.crt" ^
    "http://ts.ssl.com" ^
    %_UCS_YUBIKEY_PIN%
goto :eof

:codesign
set path=%~dp2;%~dp3;%path%

echo SHA-256 %~dpnx1 -^> %~n1_signed%~x1
"%~2" -in "%~dpnx1" -out "%~dpn1_signed%~x1" ^
    -pkcs11module "%~3" -pkcs11engine "%~4" ^
    -certs "%~5" -key "pkcs11:id=%%01" -pass "%~7" ^
    -h sha256 -ts "%~6" -nolegacy  || goto :eof    
move /y "%~dpn1_signed%~x1" "%~dpnx1" > nul
goto :eof

:codesign_legacy
set path=%~dp2;%~dp3;%path%

echo SHA-1 %~dpnx1 -^> %~n1_signed%~x1
"%~2" -in "%~dpnx1" -out "%~dpn1_signed%~x1" ^
    -pkcs11module "%~3" -pkcs11engine "%~4" ^
    -certs "%~5" -key "pkcs11:id=%%01" -pass "%~7" ^
    -h sha1 -ts "%~6" -nolegacy  || goto :eof    
echo SHA-256 %~n1_signed%~x1 -^> %~dpnx1
"%~2" -in "%~dpn1_signed%~x1" -out "%~dpnx1" ^
    -pkcs11module "%~3" -pkcs11engine "%~4" ^
    -certs "%~5" -key "pkcs11:id=%%01" -pass "%~7" ^
    -h sha256 -ts "%~6" -nolegacy -nest || goto :eof
del /q "%~dpn1_signed%~x1"
goto :eof
```

The Yubikey PIN should be set in `_UCS_YUBIKEY_PIN` environment variable or edit the source.

Unfortunately SSL.com issues only ECDSA code-signing certificates which will never work on legacy Windows XP SP3 systems so my attempts above were futile.

### Edit: Singing Web Service

Here is a cheap web service (in golang) which shells helper `s.bat` above and can be used to sign your build binaries remotely:

- [gist](https://gist.github.com/wqweto/355ec6957ef3d3c227f2b28127606df5)

Make sure to run the service executable in Console session on server, i.e. use Task Scheduler to run exe at startup (in proper folder too).

Comment: Thanks for hosting a compiled pkcs11!

Comment: This script mitigates this, but for anyone skipping steps thanks to these hosted files, an important 'gotcha' is the folder that has libykcs11 needs to be on PATH as it has dependencies in its own folder :)

Comment: It does `set path=%~dp2;%~dp3;%path%` so both  `osslsigncode.exe` and `libykcs11.dll` paths end up in PATH (in this order).

Comment: If anyone is looking for a one-liner, this is it: `osslsigncode.exe -in in.exe -out out.exe -pkcs11module libykcs11 -pkcs11engine pkcs11 -certs cert.crt -key "pkcs11:id=%%01" -pass "your_pin" -h sha256 -ts "http://ts.ssl.com" -nolegacy` You don't need to worry about the path stuff as long as you have the required dll files in the same directory as osslsigncode.exe. Those dlls are: `libcrypto-3-x64.dll`, `libykcs11.dll`, `libykpiv.dll`, `pkcs11.dll`, `vcruntime140.dll`, and `zlib1.dll`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jsign](https://ebourg.github.io/jsign/) instead of signtool (disclaimer: I'm the author), it supports Yubikeys natively and doesn't require any PKCS#11 library to be installed.

The syntax looks like this:

```
jsign --storetype PIV --storepass 123456 --alias SIGNATURE \
      --certfile full-chain.pem application.exe
```

Comment: Kind of off-topic but does Jsign work with UIAccess enabled executables? osslsigncode does not - If I was to guess its due to the signing process overwriting a shared area in the PE metadata so figured this would be a similar challenge for your tool 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-securityoverview?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: To be clear, osslsigncode will correctly produce a signed executable, its just that the UIAccess enabled features will not work (such as elevated top-most privileges like rendering over the start menu) even if the other requirements are met. 

No issue with signtool signed executables.

Comment: I'm not familiar with UIAccess, but after reading the documentation it looks to be solely determined by the application manifest and the presence of a valid signature to enable privilege elevation. It doesn't look like anything specific at the signature level is required, but I may be wrong. Try signing with Jsign, and if it doesn't work please open an issue on GitHub and I'll investigate.